# who to use tradingview chart in my website and with my data

Tags: charts

I have tried many for use the **charts** in [tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/) .
I would use the website charts in my app(website) but my datas.
please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill up some agreement form , which you can find here at

> https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/

After submitting the form they will give u access to their github private repo which has documentation and examples . If you dont have a data source right now , you can either use google or yahoo finance apis for that.

Comment: Is it possible to get the library without a company/url?

Answer (score 0):

@Rahil is correct, you need to apply for the private repo's access.

However, I can access it now, but not found any clues about how to write API using my own data for Tradingview. -_-

I will update this answer once it's done.